# Rich text in specifi word header qtableWidget

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am locking for wirte rich text in header of qtablewidget, to make one specific word in italic like on the qlabel. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: You can start from [`paintSection()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#paintSection).

Comment: @musicamante thank you for your response. Can you give more details please ? paintSection can be used with rich text ?

Comment: It's a function that draws each header section with the given QPainter, so you should read the QPainter documentation. If you need rich text content, you also need to use QTextDocument().